# EF Code First Data Annotations and Inheritance

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I am using code generation to create sets of entities and I want to be able to set them up like so:

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person_Generated {
   [Key]
   [Column("PersonId")]
   public virtual int? PersonId { get; set; }
}

public class Person : Person_Generated { }
```

This will allow me to add/override custom properties later in the Person class. The problem is, when I try to query using **Person** I get this error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The type 'Person' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.
```

Comment: I've already tried playing with the [NotMapped] attribute but that gives NotMapped error when trying to use Person.

Comment: Can primary key be nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went with using partial classes since it seems inherited classes have issues.